# Сколько чисел представимо данным типом

Tags: c++

Как узнать, сколько чисел представимо данным типом, кроме `std::pow(2., sizeof(type)*8)`?

Comment: `1 << (sizeof(type)*8)` не считается?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, конечно, числовые типы? Для пользовательских типов понятие «разные значения» довольно размыто.

Comment: @vp_arth, это типичный случай UB (две ошибки на одну строку кода и обе UB).

Answer (score 1):

Для целочисленных типов кол-во различных вариантов может быть получено путём вычитания минимально возможного значения из максимально возможного и добавления единицы, т.е.:

```
std::numeric_limits<T>::max() - std::numeric_limits<T>::min() + 1;
```

Но здесь стоит учесть тот момент, что для типов с рангом `>= int` мы получим переполнение и результат в виде нуля. Чтобы этого не произошло нужно привести первый аргумент к некоторому максимально возможному целому типу. Назовём его пока `BigInt`.

```
static_cast<BigInt>(std::numeric_limits<T>::max()) - std::numeric_limits<T>::min() + 1;
```

Этот подход увеличит кол-во типов, для которых можно вызывать код, но переполнение всё равно будет возникать для ситуаций, когда `sizeof(T) == sizeof(BigInt)`. И этого не избежать, т.к. любой тип будет иметь представление для нуля, а стало быть кол-во возможных вариантов как минимум на единицу больше, чем максимально представимое этим типом число.

Для демонстрации в качестве `BigInt` я выбрал нестандартный, но имеющийся в различных компиляторах тип `__int128_t`:

```
template <class T>
auto range() {
    return static_cast<__int128_t>(std::numeric_limits<T>::max()) - std::numeric_limits<T>::min() + 1;
}
```

Проверка (код для вывода значения типа `__int128_t` заимствован из [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25115163/3240681) [James Kanze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/649665/james-kanze), т.к. готовых решений компиляторами не предоставляется):

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

std::ostream&
operator<<( std::ostream& dest, __int128_t value )
{
    std::ostream::sentry s( dest );
    if ( s ) {
        __uint128_t tmp = value < 0 ? -value : value;
        char buffer[ 128 ];
        char* d = std::end( buffer );
        do
        {
            -- d;
            *d = "0123456789"[ tmp % 10 ];
            tmp /= 10;
        } while ( tmp != 0 );
        if ( value < 0 ) {
            -- d;
            *d = '-';
        }
        int len = std::end( buffer ) - d;
        if ( dest.rdbuf()->sputn( d, len ) != len ) {
            dest.setstate( std::ios_base::badbit );
        }
    }
    return dest;
}

template <class T>
auto range() {
    return static_cast<__int128_t>(std::numeric_limits<T>::max()) - std::numeric_limits<T>::min() + 1;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << range<int>() << "\n"
    << range<unsigned>() << "\n"
    << range<long>() << "\n"
    << range<char>() << "\n"
    << range<short>() << "\n"
    << range<unsigned long long>() << "\n"
    << range<bool>() << "\n";
}
```

[Возможный вывод:](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/z4o4DLSlRD3kR7eA)

> ```
> 4294967296  
> 4294967296  
> 18446744073709551616  
> 256  
> 65536  
> 18446744073709551616  
> 2
> ```

Вариант с `std::make_unsigned`, предложенный в другом ответе, не будет работать для типа `bool`, т.к. он не имеет возможности быть знаковым или беззнаковым.

Comment: Вариант с `make_unsigned` формально не работает ни с какими типами, ибо языком не гарантируется никакой связи между количеством представимых значений соответствующих знаковых и беззнаковых типов.

Answer (score 0):

С++11
 `std::numeric_limits<type>::max()`

Comment: это максимальное число

Answer (score 0):

не уверен, но можно опробовать так:

```
unsigned int ui = 0;
int i = (x - 1)/2
```

вообще вроде в библиотеке `limits.h` есть `INT_MAX`

Comment: в первом непонятно что, во втором - максимальное

Comment: user238526, а вам что надо?

Comment: а я понял вам надо для любого типа

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл:

`std::numeric_limits<std::make_unsigned<my_type>::type>::max()`

Comment: интересно, а как быть с вещественными числами (в смысле с double, float)

Comment: Это - максимальное представимое значение. А вот количество разных представимых значений - не всегда просто 2^{кол-во битов}...